# ShareKit support iOS 5 now?

Tags: ios5, sharekit

ShareKit (https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit ) can support iOS 5 now ?

For such similar back-compatibility issue, what are the essence for developers to think about? Need think about ARC? or do they need to think about using storyboard to replace xibs?  Any good practices guidelines to handle such issues?

Thanks for any clues or comments to understand this problem.

Comment: I don't think ShareKit needs to worry about Storyboard.  I would think ShareKit's biggest issue, in moving forward is supporting ARC.  I'm really glad ShareKit is moving towards a more community based approach, because it was becoming painful to use.

Answer (score 3):

Sharekit will work fine with storyboards.  ARC will be your biggest problem.  You will have to go through every class in Sharekit and tell it to ignore ARC (`-fno-objc-arc` - under build phases - although be warned your going to have to do this for like 60 classes).

I personally don't think its very difficult to integrate Facebook with their new, easier API.  And Twitter is so easy in iOS 5.  That being said, if you want more sharing services than those, or cannot figure out how to implement Facebook or Twitter, go with Sharekit and you should have no problems.

Comment: Select all the files in the build phase by clicking the topmost one, then holding shift and pressing the bottom-most one.  Then press 'enter' and a dialogue pops up.  Type -fno-objc-arc then press enter again.  No need to do each one manually.  =)  And after all that, ShareKit still won't work.  =(

Comment: Good call.  I didn't realize you could do that all at once

Answer (score 2):

If you try to build it in iOS 5, you will get a lot of warnings. Also you'll probably have some cancel issue in twitter but sharekit people are doing the fix immediately.

[sharekit twitter cancel issue](https://github.com/ideashower/ShareKit/issues/254)